# How do I access a variable outside of an foreach (C#)

Tags: c#, foreach

I'm trying to get the variable result from a foreach in my main method. The code looks like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ArrayList lines = GetLines("test.txt", "8394", true);
        foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            string result = s;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

As you can see it returns an error because I cannot access the variable outside of the foreach.
How do I access it?

Comment: You need to define it outside the `foreach`, if you want to access it outside the `foreach` ....

Comment: Who did downvote this and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot understand what do you want to achieve... but the code should be this:

```
 ArrayList lines = GetLines("test.txt", "8394", true);
 string result=string.Empty;       
 foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            result = s;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

I think you want do to something like this:

```
 ArrayList lines = GetLines("test.txt", "8394", true);

 foreach (string s in lines)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
```

Comment: Whats the point of iterating when you want to display only the last value??

Comment: Thanks alot! I even got it to work as a method with that snippet :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong logically. You loop through some lines, assign them to a variable, then do **nothing** to it, then assign the next line to a new variable (each time the loop gets another line, another variable called result is created), and so on.

This could be considered a logical code:

```
string names = string.Empty;
foreach (string name in namesList)
{
    names += ", " + name;
}
console.WriteLine(names);
```

Comment: If you do something like this, you should always use a `StringBuilder` instead of just concatenating together your immutable strings.... otherwise, you're tossing out the old string and creating a new string instance for each time you iterate - **not** very efficient....

Comment: Good hint @marc_s. I was just demonstrating :)

Answer (score 1):

Declare string result outside the foreach loop

```
string result = "" ;

foreach (string name in namesList)
{
    names += ", " + name;
}
```

....etc

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

in case u want to get just current value of as above code is ok but if you want to get line you shoul write

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        ArrayList lines = GetLines("test.txt", "8394", true);
        foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            result += s;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare a variable outside the braces {} to use it outside

```
ArrayList lines = GetLines("test.txt", "8394", true);
 string result;       
 foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            result = s;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Is the obvious answer, *however* this code will only write out to the console the last parameter/item in the lines array.

It all depends what you want really, if you want to write out all the contents of the lines array, you can write line for each item by doing it within the loop. e.g.

```
ArrayList lines = GetLines("test.txt", "8394", true);
 string result;       
 foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            result = s;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

Would write every item

Answer (score 0):

The scope of any variable declared within the foreach loop is limited to the loop itself. It cannot be accessed outside the loop. As @danyolgiax mentioned, declare the variable outside the loop. Then you will be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

`Variables` can be accessed with in the `scope`. So if you want to access a variable outside the `foreach loop`, then declare it outside the loop.

```
string result = string.Empty;

foreach (string s in lines)         
{              
   result = s;         
}
```